# This function must be open if these points are isolated

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^m$ be an open and $f:U\to \mathbb R^m$ be a function of class $C^1$.

If the points where the determinant of the Jacobian Matrix of $f$ is zero are isolated ones and $m>1$, how do I prove this function must be open?

I don't know even how to begin, I need some hints.

Comment: Have you tried considering an open subset $W\subseteq U$ and an arbitrary point $y\in f(W)$ and showing that there exists an open subset $V$ of $f(W)$ for which $y\in V$ using the Inverse Function Theorem? I think the fact that the zeros of $f'$ are isolated will permit you to consider an $x\in W$ such that $f(x)=y$ and for which $f'(x)\in M_m^{-1}$  so that you can indeed apply the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: @Guest Thank you for your comment. I'm trying to understand what do you mean by your comment. What is $M_m^{-1}$?

Comment: The set of invertible $m\times m$ real matrices.

Comment: @Guest Is this $W$ arbitrary? I didn't understand where you applied the Inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are missing is the notion of the **degree** of a map. 
You can start by reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) wikipedia article (you only need the section about degree of maps from a closed region), then take a look at the references they list. But the best reference I know is "Differential Topology" by Guillemin and Pollack (not on the wikipedia list).

The setup is that you have two oriented smooth manifolds $M, N$ of dimension $m$, where $M$ possibly has boundary while $N$ has empty boundary. Suppose that $f: M\to N$ is a $C^1$-smooth proper map (proper means that preimages of compacts are compact). The degree $deg_f(y)$ is defined for $y\in N - f(\partial M)$. In the case when $y$ is a regular value of $f$,
$$
deg_f(y)=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} (\pm 1),
$$
where $1$ is used when $df: T_xM\to T_yN$ is orientation-preserving and $-1$ otherwise. In particular, if $f$ preserves orientation (at its regular points) and $y$, as above is a regular value, then $deg_f(y)$ is the cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$. An important property of degree is that it is locally constant, in particular, it is constant on each component of $N -f(\partial M)$.

Given all this, here is a proof of the claim that you are after. It suffices to consider the case when $U$ is connected. Note that the set of critical points of your map $f$ is 0-dimensional, $m>1$, hence, the critical set of $f$ does not separate $U$.  Therefore, without loss of generality, we may assume that $f$ has positive jacobian determinant $J_f(x)$ at its regular points. Openness is a local property. It is clear (by the inverse function theorem) at  the points where $J_f(x)\ne 0$, hence, consider an (isolated) critical point $x_0\in U$ of $f$. Let $B$ be a sufficiently small closed ball centered at $x_0$, $B\subset U$, I am assuming that $x_0$ is the only critical points of $f$ in $B$. Without loss of generality (for generic choice of the radius of $B$), $y_0:=f(x_0)\notin f(\partial B)$. Now, I will take $M:=B$ and consider $deg_g$ for the restriction $g$ of $f$ to $M=B$. There is a sequence of points $x_i\in B- \{x_0\}$ converging to $x_0$. Then, since $J_g$ is positive away from $x_0$ (in $B$), $deg_g(y_i)>0$, $y_i=f(x_i)$. Hence, by continuity of degree,  $deg_g(y_0)>0$. Now, if $y_0$ is not an interior point of $f(B)$, there is a sequence $z_j\notin f(B)$ converging to $y_0$. Hence, $deg_g(z_i)=0$ for all large $j$. Hence, $deg_g$ is discontinuous at $y_0$. A contradiction. Thus, $f$ is open at $x_0$. qed

Comment: So could  you say a bit more about what you mean by $deg_g(y_0)$ (i.e. the degree of a critical value)?  I'm worried, for instance, that the pre-image of $y_0$ could consist of sequence of points converging to the critical point, $x_0$.

Comment: I mean, obviously one thing you could do is look at the degree of the map $f|_{\partial B}$ when you post compose it with a projection onto a sphere around $y_0$. But with infinitely many elements of $f^{-1}(y_0)$ running around inside every neighborhood of $x_0$, I'm less certain that notion of degree is well behaved.  But maybe it is and I'm just being stupid.

Comment: @Timkinsella: Not me, this is a standard definition: Make a small perturbation of $f$ making $y_0$ a regular value, then compute as above. Use transversality to show that the definition is independent of perturbation.

Comment: I see. Thanks. .

Comment: @Timkinsella: The best reference for such arguments that I know is Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential Topology".

Comment: So, one thing that might help me is to see where your argument fails for $m=1$...

Comment: @Timkinsella: A point can separate $R^1$ but not $R^m$, $m>1$. Therefore, $J_f$ has constant sign whenever nonzero.

Comment: @Timkinsella: The sign change of $f'(x)$ is exactly what happens in your example $f(x)=x^2$. If $f'(x)\ge 0$ or $f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x\in {\mathbb R}$ then the function $f: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ is, of course, monotonic and, hence, open (provided that its set of critical points has empty interior). You can also see that for arbitrary $m$ the "right" condition is not that the set of critical points is isolated but that it does not separate $R^m$. With this condition, the case $m=1$ is no longer exceptional.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an *elementary* proof, using only the Inverse Function Theorem.

It suffices to prove the question in the case of just one singular point, i.e.,
one point where the Jacobian of $f$ (denoted as $\det f'(\boldsymbol{x}))$, vanishes. We shall then show the following:

**Claim.** *Let $m>1$ and $B_R$ be the open ball 
of radius $R$ in $\mathbb R^m$, centered at the origin, and $f:B_R\to\mathbb R^m$, continuously differentiable. 
If the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$ vanishes only at $x=0$, then $f$ is open.*

In order to show that  the above claim, it suffices to show that $f[B_r]$ is open,
for every $r<R$.

We assume for simplicity that $f(0)=0$. 
If there exists a sequence $\{\boldsymbol{x}_n\}\subset B_R\smallsetminus\{0\}$,
with $\boldsymbol{x}_n\to 0$ and $f(\boldsymbol{x}_n)=0$, then for every $r<R$, the ball $B_r$ 
contains a term $\boldsymbol{x}_n$ and as $\det f'(\boldsymbol{x}_n)\ne 0$, then $f[B_r]$ contains 
an open ball centered at $f(\boldsymbol{x}_n)=0$. Let's now assume that no such sequence 
exists, which implies that there exists an $\varrho_1\in (0,R)$, such that
$$
f(x)\ne 0\quad\text{whenever $0<|\boldsymbol{x}|\le \varrho_1$}.
$$
We pick an arbitrary $\varrho\in(0,\varrho_1)$ and 
let 
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}\in C_\varrho} |f(\boldsymbol{x})|=2d,
\quad \text{where $C_\varrho=\{\boldsymbol{x}: |\boldsymbol{x}|=\varrho \}$}.
$$ 
We shall show that $B_d\subset f[B_\varrho]$. Clearly, it suffices to show that
$B_d\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}\subset f[B_\varrho\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}]$. Let
$$
V=(B_d\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\})\cap f[B_\varrho\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}]
\quad\text{and}\quad
W=(B_d\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\})\!\smallsetminus\! f[B_\varrho\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}].
$$
It suffices to show that both $V$ and $W$ are open, since $B_d\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}$ is connected.
(In fact, here is the only place where we use the requirement that $m>1$.) The set $V$ is
open as a consequence of the Inverse Function Theorem. It remains to show that $W$ is
also open.

Let $\,\boldsymbol{w}\in W$. 
Since $\,\boldsymbol{w}\not\in f[B_\varrho]$, 
then the function $\,g:\overline{B}_\varrho\to\mathbb R^m$, defined as
$$
g(\boldsymbol{x})=|f(\boldsymbol{x})-\boldsymbol{w}|^2,
$$ 
does not vanish 
and hence it attains a minimum in some $\boldsymbol{x}_0\in\overline{B}_\varrho$, where 
$\overline{B}_\varrho$ is the closed ball of radius $\varrho$ centered at the origin. In particular, 
$|\boldsymbol{x}_0|<\varrho$, since for $\boldsymbol{x}\in C_\varrho$ we have
$$
g(\boldsymbol{x})=|f(\boldsymbol{x})-\boldsymbol{w}|^2>\big(|f(\boldsymbol{x})|-|\boldsymbol{w}|\big)^2>
\big(2d-d\big)^2=d^2>|\boldsymbol{w}|^2=g(0).
$$
Therefore, since the continuously differentiable function
$g$ attains a local minimum at $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, then its gradient
vanishes at $\boldsymbol{x}_0$
$$
0=\nabla g(\boldsymbol{x}_0)=2f'(\boldsymbol{x}_0)\big( f(\boldsymbol{x}_0)-\boldsymbol{w}\big),
$$
and since $f(\boldsymbol{x}_0)-\boldsymbol{w}\ne 0$, 
the matrix $f'(\boldsymbol{x}_0)$ is not invertible and therefore
$\det f'(\boldsymbol{x}_0)=0$.
Now, since $\det f'(\boldsymbol{x})$ vanishes only for $\boldsymbol{x}=0$, 
then $\boldsymbol{x}_0=0$, which
implies that for every $\boldsymbol{x}\in \overline{B}_\varrho$
$$
|f(\boldsymbol{x})-\boldsymbol{w}|^2=g(\boldsymbol{x})\ge g(0)=|\boldsymbol{w}|^2.
$$
This means that the whole open ball of radius $|\boldsymbol{w}|$ centered 
at $\boldsymbol{w}$ does not intersect
the set $f\big[\overline{B}_\varrho\big]$, and hence $W$ is open, which concludes the proof of the Claim.