# Injectivity of a holomorphic function on a dense set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

Suppose we have a holomorphic injective function $f:B_1(0)\setminus\{x\}\to  B_1(0)\setminus\{x\}$ where $B_1(0)$ is the unit ball and $x\in B_1(0)$. Now since $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $x$ we may extend it to a function $g$ holomorphic to all $B_1(0)$

> I want to prove that $g$ is still injective. My idea was that $B_1(0)\setminus\{x\}$ is a dense subset of $B_1(0)$ so we can find a sequence $x_n$ inside $B_1(0)\setminus \{x\}$ converging to $x$. Then $g'(x)=g'(lim x_n)=lim g'(x_n)$ where all $g'(x_n)\not=0$ but this is not enough to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Assume that $\,g:B(0,1)\to B(0,1)\!\smallsetminus\!\{x\}\,$ is not $\,1\!-\!1$. Hence, there exists a $\,y\in B(0,1)\!\smallsetminus\!\{x\}$, such that $\,g(x)=g(y)$.

Open Mapping Theorem implies that if $g$ holomorphic and non-constant then for every $U$ open, so is $g[U]$. Let $0<\delta<|x-y|/3$, then $\,w=g(x)=g(y)\in g[B(x,\delta)]\cap g[B(y,\delta)]$. But as $g[B(x,\delta)]\cap g[B(y,\delta)]$ is open, then there exists an $r>0$, such that
$$
B(w,r)\subset g[B(x,\delta)]\cap g[B(y,\delta)].
$$
Hence, every value in $B(w,r)$ is taken at least twice by $f$.

Comment: I really like this answer! One small question: $g$ doesn't necessary map into $B(0,1) \backslash \{ x \}$, does it? For example, if $f: B(0,1) \backslash \{ x \} \to B(0,1) \backslash \{ x\}$ is $f(z) = z$, then $g(z) = z$, so $g(x) = x$. (I wonder if we can prove that $g(x) = x$ in all cases...).

Comment: Not necessarily. Take for example $f(z)=(z+1)/2$ : $B(0,1) \!\smallsetminus\! \{0\}\to B(0,1)\!\smallsetminus\!\{0\}$

Comment: Clear and detailed answer. Nice job ! Thank you

Comment: Just one thing: what could it be a generalization of this fact? Is it true for every dense subset ?

Comment: Generalisations in which direction? See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092954/this-function-must-be-open-if-these-points-are-isolated