How to show a mapping is open?
The exercise goes as follows:
Let $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^n; U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set with $n > 1$, be a $C^1$ function whose  points where the Jacobian determinant vanishes are all isolated. Prove that $f$ is an open mapping.
I know that a function being $C^k, k\ge 1$ and having its Jacobian determinant $\ne 0$ implies it is a diffeomorphism and therefore an open mapping, so if S is the set of points where $\det Jf(x) = 0$, then $f|_{U - S}$ is an open mapping. But what do I do with the points of S? And where does the supposition $n > 1$ come into play here?

$f(x)=x^2$ is not an open mapping.

Yes, but the exercise asks f to be between spaces of dimension > 1

You asked about the $n>1$ which is what my comment addressed.

Ah, I am sorry, I am not very smart

This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092954/27978

Thank you very much!
